# Unable to use @DataJpaTest if Spring security is on classpath

Tags: java, testing, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to update my test cases to use the `@DataJpaTest`. However, I am encountering some issues that appear to be related to Spring Security. The following is an example of the test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ExampleRepositoryTest  {

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Inject
    private ExampleRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
       ...
    }
```

I keep getting the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` due to the missing bean `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor`.

The project is a RESTful application with Spring security. The original test case created a full Spring Boot context using `@SpringBootTest`. The `@DataJpaTest` is supposed to help me test the JPA slice, which is exactly what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @pacoverflow sorry but I never did find out the problem. I simply reverted back to the old `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: For anyone else who runs into this problem, I was able to solve it by replacing the `@DataJpaTest` annotation with the following annotations:  `@SpringBootTest(classes={NameOfTestClass.class})`, `@AutoConfigureDataJpa`, `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager`, `@Transactional`, `@EntityScan("model.class.package.name")`

Comment: I've been trying to get around this issue as well and have attempted to follow your setup, but seem to be running into some issues. DataJpaTest would auto run hibernate DDL statements if you're using H2, but in this scenario it doesnt seem to be working, looking further it seems as the EntityScan annotation isn't being respected. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. 
for my case, I have added `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableResourceServer` on the same class. 
when I move `@EnableResourceServer` to another configuration class, the error is gone.